# PDF Plotting from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, sql-server, pdf

I am experiencing a very annoying phenomenon at the moment when trying to plot an A0 PDF Plot and would be interested to hear if anyone has had a similar problem and whether there is a solution or workaround.

I have exported a map consisting of vector layers with raster background in A0 Format to pdf with ArcGIS 10.3.1. The exported PDF dokument looks fine when opened in PDF Reader. When I plot it with our HP T1300 plotter using the HPGL Driver I can see a straight diagonal line crossing through the whole map. This line does not exist in the sde Featureclass!

I used to have similar problems with ArcGIS 9.3.1 and a simple geometry check and repair would usually solve this. As this the data comes out of an MSSQL SDE the check/repair geometry tools is not available for use. Apparently the geometries are already repaired by importing into the sde.

Is this a common problem and are there any tried and tested solutions?

Comment: Have you tried the Print as Image option?  I assume Reader has that option; I know the standard & Pro do in the Advanced options.

Comment: sounds like a issue we have had, workaround export to ai and use illustrator to set the page size or if > no illustrator use eps (embed fonts) instead and print file (do you have a RIP on your printer like posterjet?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem where printing from PDF to an HP4000 plotter  would result in odd lines being added to the final plot.  Changing the printer driver to a post script printer driver solved the problem.  The post script printer driver was an option when connecting to the plotter via CITRIX.

Answer (score 3):

I having the same problem (Yellow lines randomly being added) with a series of vector maps I was printing.  I was able to solve it by opening the pdf in Acrobat and going to the "Advanced Options" tab in "Print" under the "Properties" button. There is an option under "Printer Features" for "Max. Application Resolution".  Instead of the default I chose 300.  This, for some reason, got rid of my strange lines.

(Our plotter is and HP Designjet T1100 44in. Your mileage may vary, depending on your printer)

Comment: dpi = 300 has fixed printing issues for me in the past as well.  I'd sometimes have missing features and strange lines upon export. This would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved various other PDF printing problems by opening the PDF and printing not from Adobe Reader, but in a lightweight freeware PDF reader, of which there are many, free for the download.

Answer (score 0):

I see this occasionally and seemingly randomly.

My workaround: I open up the pdf in photoshop to rasterize the pdf, then save and reprint. If you don't have photoshop you could export as .tif then save as pdf - which does the same thing... I'm sure you aren't looking for a hack though.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues, have you tried saving different versions of your pdf export?

Occasionally i find that if i continue to write with the same filename my pdf lines will look blurred. I was using aerial imagery (rasters) with footprint and boundary (vector) lines. The vector lines wouldn't convert to pdf without distortion. When i logged a ticket into Esri support they suggested that i save the file to another name instead of trying to overwrite the original pdf export, which worked and is now a part of my work flow to number pdf exports with versions.